# Unity: Script on Object disappears when enter Play Mode

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I attached the Zombie Prefab to the Zombie Object; however, when I press Play, the script disappears on the Zombie Object. How do I ensure that the script remains on the Object when I press Play?

I declared my variable and initialized it. I know it's something basic but your help would be greatly appreciated!

```
public class PlayerLifeCollider : MonoBehaviour {

    public Zombie zombie; //declared
    public float damage = 1;

    public void Start()
    {
        zombie = GetComponent<Zombie>(); //instantiated
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        zombie.DamagePlayer(damage); //**Null error here**
    }   
}
```

---

```
public class Zombie : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int currentHealth;
    private Player player;
    private PlayerLifeCollider playerCollider;
    public int damage;

    public void Start()
    {
        playerCollider = GetComponent<PlayerLifeCollider>();
    }

    public void Damage(int damageAmount)
    {
        currentHealth -= damageAmount;
        if (currentHealth <= 0)
        {
            playerCollider.ObjectsInRange.Remove(gameObject);
            gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }

    }

   public void DamagePlayer(float damage)
    {
         player.Life(damage);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour {

public float playerLife = 100;

public void Life (float damage)
    {
        playerLife -= damage;
        if (playerLife <=0)
        {
            playerLife = 100;
            SceneManager.LoadScene(2);
        }
}
```

---

[Before Zombie Attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGG05.png)

[After Zombie Not Attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J80eo.jpg)

Comment: What is the implementation of `player.Life(float)`?

Comment: There's no need to assign `zombie = GetComponent<Zombie>()` if it is already assigned in the inspector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you're overwriting the value of `zombie` at runtime, causing it to be replaced with a null value. The code:

```
public void Start()
{
    zombie = GetComponent<Zombie>(); //instantiated
}
```

attempts to retrieve a `Zombie` script component from the parent GameObject (PlayerLifeCollider) - but there isn't a `Zombie` script on PlayerLifeCollider! So it returns null and assigns it to the variable `zombie`.

Because you have already assigned a value to `zombie` through dragging it onto the public variable in the inspector, you don't need to assign a value to it at runtime. You can safely delete this line and that value will be preserved.

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: How do you know when to assign a value to an Object through dragging or by GetComponent<GameObject>()?

Comment: @MrHero It's often most convenient to just make a variable public and drag a value onto it, since you don't need to get a reference to the object that it's on through script (so you can call `GetComponent()`). But when you need to retrieve scripts from objects created at runtime (eg. Via instantiated prefab), you can't drag them onto the variable beforehand (because they don't exist), so you'll need to retrieve them with `GetComponent()`. Doing it at runtime also makes your script easier to reuse across scenes, because you don't need to drag objects onto its variables each time you add it.